# Switch to login returning element type is invalid in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am struggling to connect my login and signup pages to my home page in React.

This is the general structure of my project

```
--src
  --assets
  --components
    --elements
    --layout
    --login_components
      Login.js
    --signup_components
      Signup.js
  --layouts
  --utils
  --views
App.js
index.js
```

This is what I have in my App.js

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import AppRoute from './utils/AppRoute';
import ScrollReveal from './utils/ScrollReveal';
import Login from './components/login_components/Login';
import Signup from './components/signup_components/Signup'

// Layouts
import LayoutDefault from './layouts/LayoutDefault';

// Views 
import Home from './views/Home';

// Initialize Google Analytics
ReactGA.initialize(process.env.REACT_APP_GA_CODE);

const trackPage = page => {
  ReactGA.set({ page });
  ReactGA.pageview(page);
};

const App = () => {

  const childRef = useRef();
  let location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    const page = location.pathname;
    document.body.classList.add('is-loaded')
    childRef.current.init();
    trackPage(page);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <ScrollReveal
      ref={childRef}
      children={() => (
        <Switch>
          <AppRoute exact path="/" component={Home} layout={LayoutDefault} />
          <AppRoute exact path="/login" /> component={Login} />
          <AppRoute exact path="/signup" /> component={Signup} />
        </Switch>
      )} />
  );
}

export default App;
```

my Login.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Login</h3>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and Signup.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Signup extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Sign Up</h3>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

When I try to visit /login I get the error

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Context.Consumer`.
```

And on my console

```
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

Comment: So it is a typo error like @TomS said in his answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a problem here:

```
<AppRoute exact path="/login" /> component={Login} />
<AppRoute exact path="/signup" /> component={Signup} />
```

You're closing your AppRoute before the component. It should be:

```
<AppRoute exact path="/login" component={Login} />
<AppRoute exact path="/signup" component={Signup} />
```

Are you using an IDE like Visual Studio or WebStorm? If so, it should have complained about it. If not, then time to look at one as it will help prevent against errors like this in future!